# Setting SameSite=None and Secure in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, web-config, samesite

Read about the `SameSite` changes enforced to prevent Cross-Site Forgery.
Source: https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/developers-get-ready-for-new.html

I'm trying to set its value to "None" and use `Secure` as advertised.

My current `web.config` setting is as below:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" 
       timeout="20" 
       cookieSameSite="None" 
       xdt:Transform="Replace" 
       xdt:Locator="Match(cookieless)"/>
  </system.web>
```

Documentation Soure: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.sessionstatesection.cookiesamesite?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_Configuration_SessionStateSection_CookieSameSite

But still I get the below error:

```
A cookie associated with a resource at `mywebsite.net` was set with `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies marked `SameSite=None` if they are also marked `Secure`.
```

How do I specify `secure` attribute in the above web.config file ? Any leads will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this link from Microsoft, sessionState doesn't have that attribute so it falls back to the httpCookies section.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite
Hope that helps.

Comment: So, we should fall back and use something like `<httpCookies requireSSL="true">` in web.config ?

Comment: YES is the answer to that comment question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set it per cookie creation

```
using SameSiteMode = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode;
....
context.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(cookie.Key, cookie.Value,
 new CookieOptions { SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,Secure = true });
```